# spring tool suite error al abrir marketplace

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Desde que actualicé mi sts no me permite abrir el *marketplace* ni ningún link que sea del marketplace. Siempre me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: Pantallazo del error]

Por si no se apreciara, el error al darle en detalles dice:

> Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
>   Cannot install remote marketplace locations: org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.ServiceLocator cannot be cast to org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator
>   org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.ServiceLocator cannot be cast to org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator
>   org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.ServiceLocator cannot be cast to org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator
>   org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.ServiceLocator cannot be cast to org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator

Answer (score 2):

Para solucionarlo se debe correr el eclipse, o cualquier IDE basado en eclipse como el spring-tool-suite, con el parámetro `-clean`.
Si no se supiera donde se ubica el ejecutable, basta con el *link*, se abre una consola se arrastra el acceso directo y se le agrega el parámetro `-clean` como se puede apreciar en la siguiente imágen.

[image: Ejemplo de solución]

**NOTA:** tardará en iniciar más de lo normal.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jek2Y-U6wSs

ahí esta la solución a tu problema. a mi me sirvió.

Comment: lo mejor es agregar un ejemplo

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.